# clasp : unknown option creds

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

[image]

I'm trying to run apps script locally using clasp. I'm following https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md to get set up . I'm logged in. Foolowing the directions:

```
$ clasp login
Logging in globally...
� Authorize clasp by visiting this url:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google........

Authorization successful.

Default credentials saved to: ~\.clasprc.json (C:\Users\me\.clasprc.json).


$ clasp open --creds
error: unknown option `--creds'
```

My project files are on the E drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to `clasp open --creds` was added in commit [`0cd4d12`](https://github.com/google/clasp/commit/0cd4d12ce27fdf9196c2fc658dcf64d000842415). This commit came after the current release of [`1.7.0`](https://github.com/google/clasp/releases/tag/1.7.0)

If you are not self-compiling `clasp`, then you do not have this functionality yet. To compile clasp, review the [developer guide](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/1.7.0/docs/develop.md).

Comment: Thank you very much . Is there a way to get a mnore recent version for windows?

Answer (score 2):

If you are to lazy to clone the clasp project, build it to finally use the `--creds` option, you can just open the url:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=...
```

with the parameter `project` with a value like: `project-id-7006438181792679938`